# Mention Users Group via Slack API

Tags: slack, slack-api

I would like to mention Users Group via Slack API (Rest), is it possible? I tried via 
    `@admins`, `<@admins>`, `<@ID>`, `<!admins>`

But it still is showed as a standard text, without mention. Any ideas?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

User Groups follow the format `<!subteam^ID|handle>`. (`subteam` is literal text. `ID` and `handle` are replaced with the details of the group.) These indicate a User Group message, and should cause a notification to be displayed by the client. User Group IDs can be determined from the `usergroups.list` API endpoint. For example, if you have a User Group named `happy-peeps` with ID of `S012345`, then you would use the command `<!subteam^S012345|happy-peeps>` to mention that user group in a message.

https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/formatting#mentioning-groups

Comment: Push notifications is not being sent to users of the group if mentioned through webhook. They are notified if mentioned manually on slack. Is this a bug in slack end?

Comment: Here's how you can get the ID for a given subteam. 1. Log into slack in a webbrowser. 2. On the left bar click "People and user groups". 3. By default this screen only shows people. You need to click the tab at the top, center of the screen that lists the User Groups. 4. Click the usergroup you want the ID for. 5. The ID is the very end of your webbrowser's url. So if your URL is https://app.slack.com/client/TABCDEFGHIJKL/browse-user-groups/user_groups/S1234AB5CDEF, then the usergroup is S1234AB5CDEF.

Answer (score 19):

The easier way to get a usergroup ID is as following documentation; https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/formatting#mentioning-groups

In short, open Slack via web browser (not app), then check usergourp link.

[image: image from Slack documentation]

With above usergroup ID, the message could be `This is message :smile: <!subteam^SAZ94GDB8>`.

The whole format is `<!subteam^ID|handle>` but `handle` is *optional*. It is correctly replaced with usergroup name (ie, `@dev-team`) without `handle`.